# ‘mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:’ not implemented

Tags: ios7, messageui

In an iOS app of mine, eventhough I have implemented this method:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError*)error;
```

I keep seing the following message:

```
Method ‘mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:’ not implemented
```

Happily things work perfectly, nevertheless it is somewhat annoying to see this warning.

Anyone has experienced something similar and found a solution?

Comment: Well, the method implemented is: `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error` and your warning is about `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:`. Did you notice the difference?

Comment: Yes. You are right ... I didn't notice an important difference.
Thanks a lot for pointing out the error.